# Installed wordpress on localhost but button links are not working why?

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, woocommerce, localhost, permalinks

Hy! every one I am new to WordPress and working on localhost

I have installed WordPress on localhost and installed a handy store theme and woo commerce plugin for  my shop but when i click on any link and buttons on home page it does not work.
I figure out that when i click on button let say shop button, In my address bar this link appears http://localhost/kharedlao/shop  (Where kharedlao folder in which i install word press) and page does not appears.

But when i include "Index.php" in my link like http://localhost/kharedlao/Index.php/shop/ in my address bar the page appears.

I am searching on google all over but does not get any clue to solve this issue how can i link my pages with my menu buttons

Comment: Check the apache rewrite module is enabled or not?

Comment: You have to setup mod_rewrite

Comment: Thanks for fast replay but can you please tell me where can i find this file

Comment: Which Operating System and software(xampp, wamp) are you using

Comment: Wamp on Windows

Comment: @TamilSelvanC I am using wamp on windows

Comment: http://www.anmsaiful.net/blog/php/enable-apache-rewrite-module.html

Comment: Very very appreciating you solved my problem searching from previous 2 days Thanks @TamilSelvanC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Temil Selvan C There is 4 step procedure to 100% solve the problem

1) Open apache’s configuration file using your favorite text editor. The configuration file generally locates at:{apache_dir}/conf/httpd.conf

2) If you are using XAMPP or WAMP package then you will find the file at:{xampp_dir}/apache/conf/httpd.conf
{wamp_dir}/apache/conf/httpd.conf
Search for the following string:#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so and uncomment it (remove the ‘#’ sign).

3) Now search for another string AllowOverride None and replace it by AllowOverride All
4) Finally save the changes, close your text editor and restart your apache server.

That’s all.